# Глобальные и локальные переменные в си

Tags: c, область-видимости

Не могу разобраться. Допустим у меня есть 2 файла в проекте. Один main.c, другой fo.c. В файле fo.c есть переменная, допустим float a, которая объявлена не внутри функций. Делает ли это эту переменную глобальной? Т.е на неё будет выделена память на всё время выделение программы? ( в файле main, я не пишу никакой extern)

Comment: Или же переменная "а" , будет локальной внутри файла fo ?

Comment: чтобы она стала локальной внутри файла надо `static` писать, иначе глобальная

Comment: если я поставлю "static" переменная не станет локальной, а область видимости будет только в переделах файла. Вопрос был конкретно о том, будет ли память выделяться только в области видимости этого файла, а потом удаляться, или на всём рабочем процессе программы. Надеюсь, получил правильный ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое "память выделяться только в области видимости этого файла"??? Область видимости - чисто пространственная характеристика, а выделение и освобождение памяти - временнАя характеристика. Они никак не совместимы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Термин "глобальная переменная" недостаточно четко определен.

Ваша переменная `float a;` будет обладать *статическим классом хранения*, т.е. она будет существовать все время выполнения программы. Ваша переменная будет иметь *внешнее связывание*, т.е. к ней, при желании, можно будет получить прямой доступ из любого места программы.

Но это не означает, что *имя* вашей переменной будет иметь некую глобальную *область видимости* (в С нет такой области видимости вообще). Чтобы получить доступ к вашей переменной из других единиц трансляции, вам придется дополнительно выполнить *объявление* этой переменной в этих других единицах трансляции

```
extern float a;
```

Обычно именно для *глобальных* переменных, т.е. переменных, которые потенциально "нужны везде", такое объявление помещают в заголовочный файл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это я и имел в виду. Не само то, что к ней можно обратиться, а что в памяти она хранится во всё время выполнения программы или нет.